# Can't publish more than 6 videos within one day even through the quota has been changed to 50000

Tags: quota

```
{
  "code" : 403,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "youtube.quota",
    "message" : "The request cannot be completed because you have exceeded your <a href=\"/youtube/v3/getting-started#quota\">quota</a>.",
    "reason" : "quotaExceeded"
  } ],
```

[image: Quota=50000]

[quota calculator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cl4Cy.png)

[test quota usage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UeZ7B.png)

Comment: It looks like your _Queries_ quota is 50k, not video uploads.  Who would upload 50k videos in a day!?

Comment: @EddInglis : A news company? If this user is coming from CGTN like his username suggest, it's possible...

Comment: @EddInglis I am confused, so you mean the Queries per day quota in the screenshot is not the video quota I need?

Comment: CGTNEurope, to be honest, I don't really know.  I just looked at it and it didn't really add up.  But as @Bestter says, maybe it does.  I'm going to duck out now...

Answer (score 0):

The queries or requests quota is 50k not video uplaods quota video uploads quota is 25-50 tops you can refer this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47408723/youtube-quotas-exceeded) for more information.

Hope this helps

Comment: CGTN Europe - if @FrankCastle's answer solved your issue, please accept it.